# Update and remove buttons are hidden in plugin's page

Tags: plugins, updates

I used the 'Anti-Malware Security and Brute-Force Firewall' plugin to remove a couple of malware files into a WordPress site. 
However i have the following issue: The update button has been removed from the dasboard as well as from plugin's page also. The remove plugin button is also hidden.

Comment: Well, maybe this plugin is responsible for that? Have you tried disabling it? Maybe there's a setting for that. Note that you can only delete plugins that have been previously deactivated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunatelly this issue was exists before the plugin installation and still exists even i disabled it.